# Что обозначает <E> в данном контексте?

Tags: java

```
public interface Array<E> extends Container<E> ? JAVA
```

Comment: Array<E> и Container<E>

Comment: Параметр шаблона?

Comment: почитайте про дженерики

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Означает, что сюда можно подставить любой тип, проверка которого будет на стадии компиляции. Но в рантайме эта информация будет стерта!

Можете [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/sberbank/blog/416413/) почитать более комплексную инфу. На самом то деле это очень большая тема в Java